# Microsoft flow - Get First Char from File Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, flow, microsoft-forms

I have a form that creates `.docx` files from a form / word template.

User inputs

- Firstname = Joe
- Lastname = Dirt

Then a file is created "Joe Dirt - New Hire.docx"

I like to find a way to get the first letter of the file "J" to then be able to move it to one-drive folder based on the Letter. So move J files to J folder.

I have my SharePoint document viewer all setup to file the Directory Tree "A-Z" Just cant get them in it.

I tried the variable sub string but couldn't get it right.

Anything helps. Thank you.

[image: Current FLow]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Substring() to get the first letter. Initialize a variable at the top (myVariable). Then set the variable with the function

`Substring(<First Name>,1,1)`

where `<First Name>` is the Forms field. Now you can use the variable in the Folder Path

`/Documents/<myVariable>`

Answer (score 0):

As teylyn suggested, you could add an action "Initialize variable". Then use the funtion substring to get the first char of the First name. Like this:

[image]

Read this article for more about substring:
https://www.timlinenterprises.com/microsoft-flow-substring/